# Filter on List<T>.Contains

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I need to filter a LINQ query by determining that a parameter passed into a method is in a list. I did something similar to this with another project and it worked fine but I can't get the syntax right here.

First I create a list from a value passed into the method:

```
// Create a list of category events here
var categoryList = new List<int>();
var categories = context.CategoryEvents
    .Where(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .Select(c => c.CategoryId);
if(categoryList.Any())
{
    categoryList.AddRange(categories);
}
```

Next I create my query in which I need to filter the results based on whether the parameter is in the list:

```
events = context.Events
    .Where(categoryList.Contains(categoryId)) // Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code.

1. You're selecting `CategoryId` after filtering by `CategoryId`. Did you mean to select `EventId`s instead?
2. `if(categoryList.Any())` should be `if(categories.Any())`
3. There needs to be a lambda expression in `.Where(categoryList.Contains(categoryId))`

Here's a revised version of the code that has a better chance of working...

```
var eventIdList = new List<int>();
var eventIds = context.CategoryEvents
    .Where(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .Select(c => c.EventId);
if(eventIds.Any())
{
    eventIdList.AddRange(eventsIds);
}

var eventsInCategory = context.Events
    .Where(e => eventIdList.Contains(e.EventId)); // or simply e.Id, depending on what your model looks like
```

If that works, there is a lot that can be done to improve/simplify the code.

For example, this `if` block actually executes two database queries, once for `Any()` and a second one during `AddRange()`...

```
if(eventIds.Any())
{
    eventIdList.AddRange(eventsIds);
}
```

You can actually replace the first chunk of code using `ToList()`. There is no need for `new List<int>()`, `Any()`, or `AddRange()`...

```
var eventIdList = context.CategoryEvents
    .Where(c => c.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .Select(c => c.EventId)
    .ToList();
```

And it sounds like all you're trying to do with this entire piece of code is to find all events in a given `CategoryId`. You can do this in 1 EF query...

```
var eventsInCategory = context.Events
    .Join(context.CategoryEvents,
          e => e.EventId, // or simply e.Id, depending on what your model looks like
          ce => ce.EventId,
          (e, ce) => e)
    .ToList();
```

This can be further simplified if the models are set up with the proper navigation properties. For example, if you have a `Categories` `DbSet` and it has a navigation property for all related `Event`s:

```
var eventsInCategory = context.Categories.Find(categoryId).Events;
```

Comment: Anthony you've invested a lot of time on this and I really appreciate it. I'm a TSQL guy and even after a lot of effort the many to many query syntax is not coming easy. I do have my entities set up properly with the appropriate navigation properties so it's a matter of properly constructing the query. Going to work through your suggestions now and will post my results. Thanks again.